# Instantiate ItemsPanelTemplate

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm trying to create a `ItemsControl` that has a separator between items, for example a control to create a navigation bread crumb.  I want the control to be completely generic.

My original method was to create extend `ItemsControl`, add a SeparatorTemplate property, and then have the class add separators to the `ItemsHost` of the ItemsControl.  The problem with this approach is that if you add extra items to the container panel, the ItemGenerator gets confused and the items are out of order and don't get removed correctly.

So my second plan was to create a completely new control that would emulate an `ItemsControl`, but the problem I'm running into is that I can't find a way to instantiate an `ItemsPanelTemplate`.  I would like to provide an ItemsPanel property just like `ItemsControl`, but I can't then create a panel from that template.

Can anyone think of a way to either instantiate an `ItemsPanelTemplate` or way to add controls to an `ItemsControl`'s panel without breaking the ItemGenerator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I haven't tried it myself but I would have thought you would override the `GetContainerForItemOverride` to acheive this.

You could create a new `BreadCrumbItem` control which is a templated `ContentControl` that has in its default template the typical `ContentPresenter` and whatever you want to use by default as separator all in a `Grid` or `StackPanel`.

The `GetContainerForItemOverride` generates a new instance of this `BreadCrumbItem` sets its `ContentTemplate` to the `ItemTemplate` property from your `ItemsControl` derivative (the `BreadCrumb` control?).

Your `BreadCrumb` control would also expose `BreadCrumbItemStyle` property that you assign to the `BreadCrumbItem` you create during `GetContainerForItemOverride`.

For completeness you may need to also implement the other `*Container*Override` methods in your `BreadCrumb` control.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to include the separator in the ItemContainer.  If I include it in the default template then I need manage what the last item is so I can make the separator not visible on the last item.  The other problem with including it in the ItemContainer is that it won't follow the layout of the ItemsPanel.  I want to be able to supply any ItemsPanel and have it correctly layout just as if it was another item.

Comment: @Stephan:  Good points.  Including a "LastItem" visual state may help with the extra separator "management" is unavoidable regardless of the solution. As to the orientation thats a choice the designer replacing your default panel is making they'll just have to replace the `BreadCrumbItem` template via the `BreadCrumbItemStyle` property as well.  Personally I think this a reasonable place to be.  The control does an acceptable job out of the box and can be styled beyond recognition if so desired by the consumer.

Comment: Well I decided to overload ItemsSource and then insert separators into the list and push that into the actual ItemsSource.  I know it may not be the safest way since someone can access `base.ItemsSource` themselves, but it gave me what I'm looking for.  Thanks for your help.